# One shell script to perform commands locally and remotely

Tags: shell, shell-script, ssh, rsync, root

So, here's the problem. I have a file on a remote machine available only to root, and a private-key-only no-root SSH access(I do have sudo though). I need to copy that file to the local machine, and make it as easy to use as possible (an alias or a shell script), because this will be used multiple times by different people.

Here's what I was thinking:
1. SSH to the remote machine and copy the file to some location where I have permissions
2. From the local machine, do rsync --remove-source-files for the file I just copied.

But I don't see any way to do it with just one command. Is there?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many commands you need.  If you can make it work with any number of commands, you write them in a new file that will become the script to run to do it.

Comment: Well, yeah, but If the first command is "ssh whatever", and the the second is "cp whatever", will "cp" be executed on the remote server?

Comment: Then the solution lies on the remote machine.  I don't understand why you need to automate such a weird intrusion into your own system but since you do it, why not simply change the permissions on the remote server or create a hard link with proper permissions?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can improve on the answer given by EightBitTony.

```
ssh -t user@target 'sudo cat /source/file' > output && chmod +x output
```

When more than one file is involved, I find **pax** much easier to use than rsync, not matter how often rsync is "simplified" for me.

```
ssh -t user@target 'cd /src && pax -w ./' | pax -r
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh -t user@target machine sudo cp /source/file /target/file`

The `-t` creates a pseudo-tty, so that sudo can ask for a password.  The `ssh` command takes an optional command (`sudo cp ....` in this case) which it executes on the target machine and then disconnects.

You will get prompted for the `sudo` password (i.e. user@target's password).

You can then run the `rsync`.  You can script this on the starting machine with just the two lines in a single script.